# IdentityServer4 require consent true requires API resource scope name to match audience name

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, identityserver4

I have an API resource in IdentityServer4:

```
{
    "Name": "usersservice",
    "DisplayName": "Users Service",
    "Scopes": [
        {
            "Name": "usersservice_all"
        },
        {
            "Name": "usersservice_read"
        }
    ]
}
```

I have multiple scopes associated with the UsersService API as I am utlizing [Authorization Policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies?view=aspnetcore-6.0) as a way to restrict access to the routes within the API resource based off of the scope the client has.

This works fine for every other client until we ran into one of our clients who was setup with `"RequireConsent": true`.  When that client would request the scope `usersservice_all`, the access token returned does not have that scope in it. This client is using hybrid grant type.

If I set `"RequireConsent": false` for the client, then `usersservice_all` is in the access token.

If `"RequireConsent": true` and the API resource's audience name matches the scope name:

```
{
    "Name": "usersservice_all",
    "DisplayName": "Users Service",
    "Scopes": [
        {
            "Name": "usersservice_all"
        }
    ]
}
```

then `usersservice_all` is in the access token.

Obviously, I don't want to just set `"RequireConsent": false` as that has implications. Also, I can't have a API resource per scope (i.e. usersservice_all client and scope, usersservice_read client and scope) as I can only set a single options.Audience in the API Resource:

```
services.AddAuthentication(Authentication.Bearer)
        .AddJwtBearer(Authentication.Bearer, options =>
        {
            options.Authority = Configuration.GetSection("IdentityServer:Authority").Value;
            options.Audience = Audience.UsersService;
        });
```

> This property states Gets or sets a single valid audience value for
> any received OpenIdConnect token.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't given information about what flow you are using so I'll assume Authorization Code. In that case, you probably have the consent for the client/user stored in the PersistedGrants repo but that consent does not include the usersservice_all scope.

When consent is stored, it stores the authorized scopes in the data field of the PersistedGrant object (Type field is "user_consent", btw).

Try either deleting the consent record or setting the Required property on your usersservice_all Scope object to true in which case it should ask for consent again.

Comment: I added to my question that the client is using hybrid grant type.  I get what you are saying, but it doesn't quite make sense as adding the usersservice_all scope with the audience named the same, works without needing to delete the consent record.  I did delete the user's consent which forced them to relog and the scope was still not in the token.

Comment: I can't think of a reason that matching the Resource name with the scope name would cause it to work. Are you certain it's not just a side effect of creating a new ApiResource with any name?

Comment: Yeah, I even tried adding a different scope for a completely different, already existing, API resource into the list of requested scopes and it ends up in the token.  The only delta between them is that the new scope does not contain _ and it is named the exact same as the Audience. Also, adding the different scope works without removing consent.

Comment: My team had taken over this code and a team member of mine just found some custom code that was incorrectly adding the Audience and not all of the Scopes.  Sorry.